# Spin Four-vector of a polarized top-quark in its center-of-mass frame in a weak decay

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering-cross-section, electroweak

I am very confused about how the spin-four-vector of a polarized top-quark in its center-of-mass frame should look like in a weak decay. Could you help me, please?

The definition of the spin four-vector is
$s=\frac{2\lambda}{m_t}(|\vec{p}|, E_t \hat{p})$. The top-quark is polarized into the z-direction with spin +1/2 and decays weakly. Since the top-quark is in its center-of-mass frame: $|\vec{p}|=0$. $\hat{p}$ is the momentum direction of the quark. This is not clear to me, since the top-quark can't have a momentum direction in its center-of-mass frame. Is this the direction of the polarization of the quark?

If the quark is polarized into the z-direction it should be $\hat{p}=\hat{e}_z$ and since the helicity of the top-Quark is negative in a weak decay it should be $\lambda=-1/2$ and so $s=-(0,\hat{e}_z)$.

Otherwise I think that the momentum of the quark must be opposite of the spin-direction since it has a negative helicity. Then it would be $\hat{p}=-\hat{e}_z$ with $\lambda=-1/2$ and so $s=(0,\hat{e}_z)$.

What does $\hat{p}$ stand for? Which term takes the spin-direction into account? My sources confuses me totally.

Comment: Where does this come from: "Since the top-quark is in CMS: $|\vec{p}|=0$."? It seems plausible that the momentum vector of most collision products is close to zero _on average_, but that doesn't prevent any _individual_ top quark from having a nonzero momentum vector.

Comment: @probably_someone It is in the CMS of the top-quark, so the top-quark has $|\vec{p}|=0$

Comment: Oh, CMS here means "center-of-mass system"! Sorry, I thought you were referring to the CMS detector. It would clear up some future confusion if you changed "CMS" to "center-of-mass frame" wherever it occurs.

Comment: In any case, where are you getting that formula for the spin four-vector? This looks different than the normal one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_angular_momentum#Four-spin

Comment: @probably_someone This paper page 14: http://inspirehep.net/search?ln=de&ln=de&p=Haber%2C+Spin+Formalism+and+Applications+to+New+Physics+Searches&of=hb&action_search=Suchen&sf=earliestdate&so=d&rm=&rg=25&sc=0

Comment: Just a guess: the $\hat{p}$  is the direction of momentum of the top quark , depending on other context , which defines the z direction in  their analysis.